Minimal values of image of a complex polynomial
Suppose we have a nonconstant entire function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. A consequence of Casorati-Weierstrass is that, if there are constants $R_0, C, s$ such that
$f(\mathbb{C}\setminus K_R(0)) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus K_{CR^s}(0)$ for all $R>R_0$,
then $f$ must be a polynomial.
Is the inverse true as well? Does this hold for any complex polynomial?

Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$, with $a_n\neq0$. Let $R_0=2\max(1,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_k|/|a_n|)$. Let $|x|>R>R_0$. Then $|f(x)|\geq |a_n|||x|^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_k||x|^k/|a_n||\geq |a_n|(|x|^n-|x|^{n-1}R_0/2)\geq |a_n|R^n$. You can see in there Lagrange's bound for the roots of a polynomial.

Just to guess at unexplained notation: "$K_r(c)$" is the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $c$, i.e., ${z \in \Bbb{C} : |z-c| \leq r}$?

Correct @EricTowers. I thought this was standard notation.

@Ben1669 : I once believed there was standard notation for some things.  Now ...  when I see a notation used twice the same way by the same author I'm a little surprised and when twice the same way by different authors I'm very surprised.
